# SQL - Run Select Statement Based On Where Query

Tags: sql, t-sql

Hi i want to create a query which does the following. When the paramter 25 is selected it only runs part A of the query, if any other number is selected run both Table A and B select queries.

Example Below:

```
DECLARE @Type varchar (200)

select * from 

(SELECT sort_code FROM dbo.Test 1
 WHERE FUNDING_YEAR = 26)



union
(SELECT sort_code FROM dbo.Test 2
 WHERE FUNDING_YEAR = 26)
Where case when @Type = 25 then select * from table2 else table 1
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: I will be using this query in a SSRS Report afterwards.
So in the SSRS Report if you select @type = 25 then  it will only run " select * from table2 else table 1" else from table 2

Comment: I would write as a stored procedure that you can pass the parameter of the type and funding year... if the parameter is type 25, then return the one result, otherwise the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to reference the variable in the `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE @Type = 25

UNION

SELECT *
FROM TableB
```

The query above will always select everything in TableB and will only select everything in TableA when the variable is equal to 25.

Comment: Thank you was just over thinking the task, this simply just solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SSRS, what I would do is write the query to return all of the rows and then apply a filter in the SSRS report when the Paramater is 25.  I wouldn't pass a paramater value to the SQL side unless it greatly reduces the run time of the query.

(I would have put this in a comment.)

Comment: Why would you choose this method over filtering in the SQL query? What benefit does it have?

Comment: It is more of a pick one way to filter the data.  We had a SSRS writer that would do both.  He would send a paramter to a query and then filter it further on the report.  

The specific scenario that @Bains21 is talking about, the best course of action is to bring in all the data and then filter in the report since sometimes he wants all the data and sometimes not.

Comment: I disagree that's the best option. Every time the user changes the parameter and runs the report again, ALL of the data has to be routed across the network. Regardless of how much data you are returning you should [avoid using dataset filters in SSRS](http://dataap.org/blog/2017/02/15/avoid-using-dataset-filters-in-ssrs/)

Comment: In the comment above, using the paramater to limit the amount of data is correct when there is a lot of data.  I wouldn't bring back 10 years of sales data to just filter it, you are coorect.  This was noted in my original comment.  In the specfic example that Bains21, I had to assume that sort_code was a relatively small number of records that would not generate excessive network traffic.